# How can I change this regexp to match all keywords that are not inside an anchor

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace keywords inside some text with an anchor that opens a details window for said keyword. This is the code I use for the replacement:

```
$pattern = '%\b('.$keyword['Keyword'].')\b(?![^<]*</a>)%i';
$replacement = '<a href="#detalii_keyword_'.$keyword['CodKeyword'].'" data-toggle="modal"><strong>\\1</strong></a>';
$text = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
```

It's built to avoid words that are inside an anchor thus avoiding already replaced multi-word keywords. So I don't replace "deviz" in already replaced "detalii deviz". The exception works in every case except when the word i'm looking for is not the first word in the anchor. So, for example, it will NOT replace "deviz" in `<a>deviz detalii</a>` or just `<a>deviz</a>` but WILL replace it `<a>detalii deviz</a>`.

How should I change the pattern to make the regular expression avoid matching any word that is inside an anchor, just like I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = 'deviz <a>deviz deviz deviz</a> deviz';
$pattern = '%\bdeviz\b(?![^<]*</a>)%i';
$text = preg_replace($pattern, 'replaced', $text);

echo $text;
// 'replaced <a>deviz deviz deviz</a> replaced'
```

Your regex seems to work fine - what's the problem?